# Calculus u-substitution: Choosing between $\frac{dx}{du}$ and $\frac{du}{dx}$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, substitution

I searched and couldn't find any answers to this one. It's probably a dumb question but one that has been troubling me.

Let's say I have an integration:
 $$\int \frac{1}{3x+2}$$

It seems the correct way to solve it is by choosing $u=3x+2$.
So

$$\begin{align}u &= 3x + 2 \\
\frac{du}{dx} &= 3 \\
dx &= \frac{1}{3}du \end{align}$$

and so on the answer comes down to $\frac{1}{3}\ln(3x+2)$

My question is, why do I need to choose it specifically this way:
$ \frac{du}{dx} = 3$?
If I choose $ \frac{dx}{du} = 3$, I get $dx=3du$ , but it gives me an answer different from the above.

How do I choose which one I use as a denominator and nominator for my u substitution?

Thank you.

Comment: $\frac{du}{dx} = 3$ comes from differentiating $u=3x+2$ with respect to $x$.

Comment: It's a bad idea to omit the differentials from the integral, especially when you are just learning how to change variables.  Here you have $\int \frac {dx}{3x+2}$, I assume, so letting $u=3x+2$ we get $du=3dx$ and our integral becomes $\frac 13\times \int \frac {du}u=\frac 13\times \ln |u|+C=\frac 13\times \ln |3x+2|+C$.

Comment: You aren't "choosing" $\dfrac{du}{dx} = 3$.  It's forced by the fact that $u = 3x+2$, which is what peterwhy is saying.

Answer (score 3):

> We want to  simplify  the  denominator and  set $u=u(x)=3x+2$. Here we  consider  $u=u(x)$ being a function in  $x$.
>   \begin{align*}
> u&=3x+2\\
> \color{blue}{\frac{du}{dx}}=\frac{d}{dx}u(x)&=\frac{d}{dx}(3x+2)\color{blue}{=3}
> \end{align*}
>   On the other hand if we consider $x=x(u)$ as function in $u$ we have 
>   \begin{align*}
> x&=\frac{1}{3}(u-2)\\
> \color{blue}{\frac{dx}{du}}=\frac{d}{du}x(u)&=\frac{d}{du}\left(\frac{1}{3}u-\frac{2}{3}\right)\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{3}}
> \end{align*}
>   So, it is not reasonable to set $\frac{dx}{du}=3$.

*Note:* It's advisable to write $\int\frac{\color{blue}{dx}}{3x+2}$ which besides some other aspects indicates that $x$ is the integration variable.

Comment: So for u subs I can always use the du/dx ?

Comment: @user603864: Correct.

Comment: I see, thank you very much. This should help my performance on the  course!

Comment: @user603864: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You are incorrect in saying: $\frac{dx}{du} = 3$

You don't "choose" this.

This is a direct result of what your u-sub is.

If we let $u = 3x+2$, then differentiating both sides, we get:

$du=3 dx$

If you wanted t o have $\frac{dx}{du}$, following the equation, this must equal $1/3$, **not** $3$.